# Missing Reference to Assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to Create a socket server, and I am having issues that I am not sure how to fix.

Here is what I am using for my `project.json`:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    },
    "vtortola.WebSocketListener": "2.2.0.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "net45"
    }
  }
}
```

I then have this basic script `Server.cs`:

```
using System.Net;
using vtortola.WebSockets;

public class Server {

    public static void Main(string[] args){

        var server = new WebSocketListener(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8006));
        var rfc = new vtortola.WebSockets.Rfc6455.WebSocketFactoryRfc6455(server);
        server.Standards.RegisterStandard(rfc);
        server.Start();

    }

}
```

When I run the following command:

```
master@ubuntu:~/Documents/Chat$ dotnet run
```

I get the following error:

> Project Chat (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0) will be compiled because expected outputs are missing
>       Compiling Chat for .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0
>       /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet compile-csc @/home/master/Documents/Chat/obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.0/dotnet-compile.rsp returned Exit Code 1
>       /home/master/Documents/Chat/Server.cs(8,26): error CS0012: The type 'IPEndPoint' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>       /home/master/Documents/Chat/Server.cs(10,26): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>       /home/master/Documents/Chat/Server.cs(11,16): error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>
> Compilation failed.
>           0 Warning(s)
>           3 Error(s)
>
> Time elapsed 00:00:02.6995789

Comment: Where is the vtortola.WebSocketListener assembly from. My guess: From a .NET Framework project ;).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't import `net45` into `netcoreapp1.0`, that won't work. When you specify `imports`, you basically say: "I know those packages claim they are not compatible, but I promise they are".

The package `vtortola.WebSocketListener` only supports `net45`, so you won't be able to use it on .Net Core (though you could still use it with dotnet CLI, if you changed your framework to `net451`).

But there seems to be a beta version of `vtortola.WebSocketListener.dnx` package, which supports `dnxcore50` (previous pre-release version of .Net Core). Importing that (along with `portable-net45+win8` for the `Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow` dependency) should work. The project.json will then look like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    },
    "vtortola.WebSocketListener.dnx": "2.2.0.1-beta-00002"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [ "dnxcore50", "portable-net45+win8" ]
    }
  }
}
```

[It seems `vtortola.WebSocketListener` will also support RC2 directly in the future.](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/pull/65)

Comment: Awesome! I was able to build the project without error!

Answer (score -1):

Please import `net451` as an array element into "import" section and insert following ependency`Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility: "1.0.1-*`